# How does a fragment with a m/z ratio of 94 form when benzoic acid breaks down?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

> Hello, I don't understand how when benzoic acid forms a fragment with a m/z ratio of 94 during breakdown. I understand it is [C6H6O]+ but how does that happen, does the ring breakdown and McLafferty rearrangement occur. I can't even think of how it could rearrange itself for that to occur or if there is a different mechanism.
> [image]

Ok I got it a phenol forms by Homolytic cleavage, that also explains the low intensity since alcohols are not stable.

Comment: The peak, $\ce{[C6H6O]^+ }$ could be an artifact of impurity ($\lt 0.1 \%$). It could be $\ce{M+}$ peak of phenol, for example.

Comment: Yes that is the first thing I thought so as well at first, but this is the theoretical spectrum and it is the same everywhere online. I'm starting to get it a C=O fragments, it's not McLafferty, but it's done by none of the mechanisms that I know.

Comment: Loss of CO is a known way of fragmentation of aromatic carboxylic acids in mass-spectra. I didn't find a good description of the resulting ions, but I will point that mass-spectrometry is a high-energy process, so common chemical sensibilities may not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subtle hint may lie in the presence of the peak at $28$, which would likely represent carbon monoxide. Carboxylic acids decarboxykate to give $\ce{CO2}$, which can lose an oxygen atom under mass spec conditions to form $\ce{CO}$. The displaced oxygen plus a proton plus a phenyl radical (or oxygen plus a hydrogen atom plus a phenyl cation) could then form the apparent phenol cation.